# Multiple Upload Controller in Play Framework / Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload multiple files from a "multipart/form-data" form and have them all stored in folders with a batch ID (which is just a timestamp)

The problem is I'm only currently able to save one file.

View

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data", 'multiple -> "") {

<input type="file" name="fsa" multiple="">

<p>
    <input type="submit">
</p>

}
```

Controller

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
            request.body.file("fsa").map { fsa =>
            import java.io.File
                val filename = fsa.filename 
                val contentType = fsa.contentType
                val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
                fsa.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/"+timestamp+"/"+filename))
                Ok("File uploaded")
            }.getOrElse {
                Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
                    "error" -> "Missing file"
                )
            }
    }
```

Is this something to do with reqest.body.file only getting one file, or should i be iterating through an array or something? Not too familiar with scala yet so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out and there may be more elegant solutions, but seeing as you've been waiting 6 months, I'll show you my ugly solution:

On the frontend, I send the files to the server using XHR, appending files to the form *individually*:

```
var uploadFiles = document.getElementById("file-input").files;

var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < uploadFiles.length; i++) {
    console.log("appending " + uploadFiles[i].name);
    formData.append(uploadFiles[i].name, uploadFiles[i]);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    console.log("upload successful");
}, false);
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function updateProgress(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
        console.log("Completed: " + percentComplete);
    }
}, false);
xhr.open('POST', UPLOAD_URL, true);

xhr.send(formData);
```

The server side code:

```
object Api extends Controller {

    def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
        println("Api.upload()")
        LibraryService.uploadFiles(request.body.files)
        Ok("Upload complete")
    }
}


object LibraryService {

    val libraryRoot: String = Play.configuration.getString("library.root").get;

    def uploadFiles(files: Seq[FilePart[TemporaryFile]]) = {
        files.foreach { filePart =>
            val newFile = new File(libraryRoot + filePart.filename)
            if (newFile.exists) {
                println("The file " + newFile.getAbsolutePath + " already exists. Upload cancelled.")
            } else {
                filePart.ref.moveTo(newFile)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uploading the files as a list proved to be more challenging and I too could only get a reference to the first file in that list.